Use of pronoun "en" referring to the subject rather than indirect object
On a recent episode of "Inner French" (E156 Pourquoi Hugo s’est installé à Marseille ?, 0'19"), the host Hugo says:

Je vais tout simplement vous raconter ma vie, ce qui s’est passé dans ma vie pendant ces derniers mois, parce que je sais que ça en intéresse certains d’entre vous.

Why did he use the pronoun "en" before "intéresse" in this paragraph? I know that "en" can stand for an indirect object in order not to repeat it but, in this example, what would be the indirect object? My best guess is "de ce qui s'est passé dans ma vie pendant ces derniers mois", but that happens to be the subject of "intéresse" (well, not technically, since grammatically speaking "ça" is the subject, but semantically speaking that seems to be the case), so I think that would be incorrect. However, I cannot identify any other candidate for indirect object here.
It would also seem strange that the full sentence would be

ça intéresse certains d’entre vous de ce qui s’est passé dans ma vie pendant ces derniers mois.

which sounds strange to me (again, because the object is basically also the subject.)
I asked this question of ChatGPT and it told me it was replacing the indirect object "ce qui s'est passé (...)", but when I told it that happened to be the subject, it gave me this strange explanation:

You're absolutely correct, and I appreciate your attention to this subtle grammatical detail. Let’s revisit the construction more carefully.


In "ça en intéresse certains d’entre vous," the pronoun "en" actually does not replace the subject of "intéresse" but rather serves a different function. Here's a more accurate explanation:


Breakdown of the sentence:

"Ça" (subject): Refers to "what happened in my life."
"en intéresse": The verb "intéresser" takes direct objects (what or whom something interests). However, the "en" here refers specifically to a subset or partitive idea of interest.
"en": Is partitive and introduces the idea of "some" or "certain aspects" of "ce qui s'est passé dans ma vie."
"certains d’entre vous": Means "some of you" (who are interested).



Why "en" is used:
The use of "en" creates a partitive sense to convey "some of it interests some of you." Without "en," the sentence would lack the nuance of referring to a part or subset of the speaker's experiences. For example:

Without "en": "Ça intéresse certains d’entre vous" (This interests some of you) – generic, all-encompassing.
With "en": "Ça en intéresse certains d’entre vous" (Some of it interests some of you) – more precise, focusing on specific aspects.



Conclusion:
You're right that "en" doesn't replace the subject. Instead, it functions partitive, referring to some part of "ça." It's a stylistic choice to add precision and nuance, common in French expressions.

I thought that was just an LLM hallucination but when I asked Gemini I got a pretty similar answer. Is there such a thing as this "partitive use" of "en"?

It's just a pleonasm, frowned upon in writing only: en refers to d'entre vous.

Bear in mind that when people speak, there are truncations, interruptions, insertion of words not necessarily really meant. In short, what may look like a grammar mistake, can just be something that occurs in speech when you don't autocorrect and just keep going.

Please read the bit about sociologique: https://www.scribbr.fr/methodologie/retranscription-entretien/  It's about interviews, but applies to speech, like in a podcast. So, it's applicable here. Please tell us which episode of the podcast so we can listen to it.

IMHO, Ça en intéresse certains and Ça intéresse certains d’entre vous are heard and defensible, whereas Ça en intéresse certains d’entre vous may be heard, but would be hard to defend from a grammatical point of view. It sounds like broken French too. It's not clear why the host is saying that.
The partitive function of en "_to introduce the idea of "some" or "certain aspects" of "ce qui s'est passé dans ma vie"" is a bogus hallucination here. En has a partitive function, but its target is not "ce qui s'est passé dans ma vie". This en refers to some of the interested people. The LLMs are wrong when they assert that en refers to the last few months of the speaker's life. They blindly pile up several things they have seen in similar contexts, without realizing that en + certains d’entre vous is a duplication (see comment by Janus Bahs Jacquet).
Note that ça intéresse certains d’entre vous de ce qui s’est passé dans ma vie pendant ces derniers mois is not correct either. That de has to go. It should be: ce qui s'est passé dans ma vie pendant ces derniers mois intéresse certains d'entre vous, or ça intéresse certains d’entre vous, ce qui s’est passé dans ma vie pendant ces derniers mois (most likely in a conversation, it's rather informal).
"Bluffe tes potes avec l'IA"

a bogus hallucination? Hmm.

To be clear, the function of en in ça en intéresse certains ‘it interests some of [us/you/them]’ is partitive, as it is supposed to represent de/d’entre [nous/vous/eux] used in a partitive sense. It’s not that it’s not partitive in function as such, but rather that the partitive expression is repeated, once pronominally and once as a full-blown prepositional phrase. It’s structurally similar to saying, Je l’ai acheté le livre, where the direct object is repeated (instead of J’ai acheté le livre or Je l’ai acheté).

@JanusBahsJacquet agreed.

@JanusBahsJacquet I have updated my response and pointed to your comment.

@JanusBahsJacquet Slightly similar but more complex than Je l'ai acheté(,) le livre which is very common and can be rephrased as the extremely common Le livre, je l'ai acheté. If we do the same thing with the OP sentence, we get "Certains d'entre vous, ça en intéresse" which still sounds broken to native ears. That last sentence would work with les though:  Certains d'entre vous, ça les intéresse.

@jlliagre Je l’ai acheté, le livre extraposes the object – you can do that in English as well (“I bought it for him, the book”), but it moves the full object outside the sentence itself. If you add other elements and keep the repeated object in place, it breaks down again: Je l’ai acheté le livre pour mon père hier soir. Applying the equivalent transformation (extraposing the constituent that en stands in for) to Ça en intéresse certains d’entre vous, I’d say we’d get D’entre vous, ça en intéresse certains, which seems less broken grammatical to me, if not exactly mellifluous.

@JanusBahsJacquet In je l'ai acheté, le livre, there is no for him. I don't think D’entre vous, ça en intéresse certains would be used. It sounds strangely high-brow, as if in a speech, actually. Je l’ai acheté le livre pour mon père hier soir works if you add commas: Je l’ai acheté le livre, pour mon père, hier soir but again, pretty rare.

@Frank Oops, I think I got a few different variations mixed up. The English equivalent should of course just have been “I bought it, the book”. I didn’t think D’entre vous, ça en intéresse would be normal-sounding (it’s rather an unusual sentence constituent to extrapose – “Of/among you, it may interest some” is also very odd in English), but it should at least be grammatical.

@JanusBahsJacquet Yes, a small change that can make the sentence work: ça en intéresse certains parmi vous.

@JanusBahsJacquet The only context where D’entre vous, ça en intéresse sans doute certains would make sense, would be in a speech, where you want to use that extraposition for a rhetorical effect, at least that's what comes to mind immediately.

Is this "partitive use of en" a completely separate thing from "en standing for an indirect object preceded by de", or is it an application of the latter because "d'entre vous" is a phrase introduced by de ("de+entre vous")? If completely separate, where can I find a reference explaining its use? If merely an application of "en standing for an indirect object  preceded by de ", I'm still surprised because "d'entre vous" is not an indirect object of "intéresse," so does that mean the rule is more general than I thought and applies to any component phrases preceded by de?

@user118967 To be clear, ça en intéresse certains d'entre vous is not correct - if that's the use of en that you are referring to here?

@Frank, no, I am referring to the correct usage ça en intéresse certains. It seems en stands for d'entre vous, but that puzzles me because I thought en could only stand for indirect objects preceded by de, and d'entre vous is not an indirect object, it is a part of the direct object certains d'entre vous in the full sentence ça intéresse certains d'entre vous. So I am just not sure which rule is being applied here, and how.
